# What reasons could there be for the error "MySQL errors in row 1"

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, database

I am creating a new Node application called bamazonManager.js. Running this application will:

1. List a set of menu options:
2. View Products for Sale View Low
3. Inventory Add to Inventory Add New Product If a manager selects View
   Products for Sale, the app should list every available item: the
   item IDs, names, prices, and quantities.
4. If a manager selects View
   Low Inventory, then it should list all items with an inventory count
   lower than five.
5. If a manager selects Add to Inventory, your app
   should display a prompt that will let the manager "add more" of any
   item currently in the store.
6. If a manager selects Add New Product,
   it should allow the manager to add a completely new product to the store.

I am working on creating the database set-up in MySQL - error kept coming up saying "MySQL errors in row 1" - I probably need a second eye on this.

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS manager_viewDB;

CREATE DATABASE manager_viewDB;
use manager_viewDB;
CREATE TABLE products (
item_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
item_name VARCHAR(20) CHARACTER SET utf8,
department_name varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
item_price INT(11) DEFAULT NOT NULL,
item_quantity int(11) DEFAULT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (item_id)
);




SELECT * FROM products;
INSERT INTO products (item_name, department_name, item_price, item_quantity)
VALUES("Mini Mac", "Computers", 689, 10);
SELECT * FROM products;
INSERT INTO products (item_name, department_name, item_price, item_quantity)
VALUES("ECHO plus", "Amazon Devices", 79.99, 10);
SELECT * FROM products;
INSERT INTO products (item_name, department_name, item_price, item_quantity)
VALUES("Funny Cat Mug", "Handmade", 20, 10);
SELECT * FROM products;
INSERT INTO products (item_name, department_name, item_price, item_quantity)
VALUES("Wine Barell Top Mirror", "Home and Kitchen", 328, 10);
SELECT * FROM products;
INSERT INTO products (item_name, department_name, item_price, item_quantity)
VALUES("Hand Stamped Bracelets", "Wedding", 20, 10);
SELECT * FROM products;
INSERT INTO products (item_name, department_name, item_price, item_quantity)
VALUES("Kawaii - Animal Plush", 22, 10);
SELECT * FROM products;
INSERT INTO products (item_name, department_name, item_price, item_quantity)
VALUES("Weave Blanket - MDA",   "Handmade", 60, 10);
SELECT * FROM products;
INSERT INTO products (item_name, department_name, item_price, item_quantity)
VALUES("Retro Tiki - Cellphone", "Handbags and Accessories", 22, 10);
SELECT * FROM products;
INSERT INTO products (item_name, department_name, item_price, item_quantity)
VALUES("Handmade Leather Bag", "Handbags and Accessories", 70, 10);
SELECT * FROM products;
INSERT INTO products (item_name, department_name, item_price, item_quantity)
VALUES("Devialet Gold Phantom", "Electronics", 2990, 10);
```

Comment: You specifically mention MySQL and yet you spam tag sql server. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a few issues here.

Get rid of DEFAULT or specify the DEFAULT value when creating table.

Your item_name is only 20 characters, yet you are trying to insert names longer than that.

Also, VALUES("Kawaii - Animal Plush", 22, 10) is only 3 values when its expecting 4.

Comment: its the third line of your answer that fixed.  thanks @fanfavorite